# How do I get a persistent session working with Express.js/Nodemon?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, session, nodemon

My TypeScript server is based on [this example project](https://brianflove.com/2016/11/08/typescript-2-express-node/). Whenever `nodemon` restarts my server, whether automatic or manually, I lose my session and have to log in again. I hate this because it's a massive waste of time when done for the 1000th time. I've tried to configure my Express.js session settings, but nothing seems to be working. Here's my configuration:

```
/**
* Configure application
*
* @class Server
* @method config
*/
public config() {
    //add static paths
    this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    //configure pug
    this.app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    this.app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    //use logger middlware
    this.app.use(logger('dev'));

    //use json form parser middlware
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());

    //use query string parser middlware
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    this.app.use(cookieParser("my secret"));
    this.app.use(session({
        name: 'MyStudio',
        secret: "my secret",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 86400000,
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false
        }
    }));
    this.app.use(passport.initialize());
    this.app.use(passport.session());
    //this.app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy

    this.app.set('json spaces', 4);

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        return done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
        return done(null, user);
    });

    passport.use('local-login', new Local.Strategy(
        (username, password, done) => {
            // My custom login logic
        }
    ));

    this.app.use(methodOverride());
}
```

How do I stop Express.js from losing my session on every restart?

Comment: Use a [persistent session store](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores).

Comment: @robertklep Are cookie sessions invalidated on restart? I thought they were persistent. Is the cookie store the same as `MemoryStore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`express-session` has support for different stores (databases) to store the session data in.

The default that is used is `MemoryStore` which keeps session data in memory *for as long as the Express process runs*. When the Express process stops (for instance, when it restarts), all session data is gone.

If you want session data to survive restarts, you need to use a persistent session store. Instead of storing the session data in memory, these store the session data in (for instance) a database. There are plenty of persistent session stores available, a list of which can be found here: https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores

Comment: For some reason I got it in my head that `MemoryStore` was different than the cookie store that `express-session` does by default. Thanks for clarifying.